# How to choose Python version when making a new virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

It seems like the current global Python version provided by [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) is automatically being employed, but there seems to be no option or parameter in the commmand `mkvirtualenv` of [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mkvirtualenv) to specify a Python version.

E.g. my current global `pyenv` Python version is this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pyenv global
3.9.0a4
```

Last time, I created a virtual environment via PowerShell using the [virtualenvwrapper-powershell](https://github.com/regisf/virtualenvwrapper-powershell) in particular with this command:

```
MkVirtualEnv -Name MyEnv -Python ThePythonDistDir
```

As you can see, the `ThePythonDistDir` needs to be passed by the user and thus refers to an already existing `Python`-version installed in some directory; in my case via `pyenv-win`.

So, is there a way to choose directly with `virtualenvwrapper` a new Python version, which would then be downloaded and installed automatically?

Comment: No `virtualenv/wrapper` cannot downloaded Python. Some other tool should do that before running `virtualenv`/`mkvirtualenv`. `pyenv-win` is such a tool.

Comment: Alright, and in order to choose _which_ `Python` version exactly, one has to set the _global_ `Python` before creating a new venv with `virtualenvwrapper`, because it will always automatically adopt this very `Python` version?

Comment: This is just one solution. Naming the version explicitly every time is another.

Comment: Where/how/at which point of the procedure do I "name" the version explicitely? There is no option or parameter associated with the command `mkvirtualenv` where I could do that, could you be more precise, please?

Comment: `mkvirtualenv --python C:\Python27\python.exe`

Comment: Thanks, it's weird though that they don't mention this capability in the docs: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mkvirtualenv

Comment: It's hidden in `[virtualenv options]`: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#section-discovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the info @phd has given me in the comments, the alternatives are:

1. Option parameter to the `mkvirtualenv` - function hidden in [virtualenv options](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#section-discovery), e.g.: `mkvirtualenv --python C:\Python27\python.exe`
2. Globally activate a `Python` version of desired, e.g. via `pyenv global 3.9.0`, *before* running the command `mkvirtualenv` to create the new venv